# Javascript passing by reference issue in recursive calls

Tags: javascript, debugging, recursion, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
const reverseLinkedList = (ll) => {
  const head = new Node();
  const reversedLL = head;
  
  reverse(ll, reversedLL);
  return head.next;
}

const reverse = (ll, reversedLL) => {
  if (ll) {
    reverse(ll.next, reversedLL);
    reversedLL.next = new Node(ll.data);
    reversedLL = reversedLL.next;
  } 
}
```

I'm doing the reverse a linked list problem, but it's not running properly because I believe it's because of how javascript changes my `head` object at the same time as `reversedLL.next = new Node(ll.data);` so the linked list chaining is not persisting at the head. Is there anything I can do so that `head` doesn't change when I modify the `reversedLL`?

Comment: `reversedLL` is the same object as `head`

Comment: Oh and also updating `reversedLL` in the `reverse` function won't change it in the calling environment. JavaScript does not have pass-by-reference.

Comment: Yes but for some reason, after this executes, `reversedLL` should point to the last node and `head` should point to the first node. But instead `head` points the same node as `reversedLL`.

Comment: Again, that assignment to `reversedLL` at the end of the `if` statement changes the **local** variable `reversedLL` in the `reverse` context. It has no effect on the `reversedLL` variable in calling contexts.

Comment: Logging the `head.next.data` in the main function at the end prints out the last node though.

Comment: Think I figured out why it was failing, `reversedLL` object wasn't persisting in the callstack so I had to return it in the recursive call `reversedLL = reverse(ll.next, reversedLL);`

Comment: do you want to reverse the linked list in place or do you want to create a new reversed copy?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to `reverse` the list in place -

```js
function reverse(ll)
{ if (ll == null) return
  let p = null
  let q = ll
  while (q)
  { p = {data: q.data, next: p}
    q = q.next
  }
  ll.data = p.data
  ll.next = p.next
}

const mylist = {data: 1, next: {data: 2, next: {data: 3, next: null}}}

reverse(mylist)

console.log(JSON.stringify(mylist))
```

```js
{data: 3, next: {data: 2, next: {data: 1, next: null}}}
```

But you tagged this question with **recursion** so maybe you want to create a reversed copy instead?

```js
function reverse(ll, p = null)
{ if (ll == null)
    return p
  else
    return reverse(ll.next, {data: ll.data, next: p})
}

const mylist = {data: 1, next: {data: 2, next: {data: 3, next: null}}}

const revList = reverse(mylist)

console.log(JSON.stringify(revList))
console.log(JSON.stringify(mylist))
```

```js
{data: 3, next: {data: 2, next: {data: 1, next: null}}}
{data: 1, next: {data: 2, next: {data: 3, next: null}}}
```